# Having trouble writing data to a file

Tags: python

i am currently using this code the top part is right but i cant seem to save it to file

this my current code

```
for line in myfile:
list_of_line = line.split()
if 'Failed password for' in line:
    ip_address_port = list_of_line[-4]
    ip_address_list = ip_address_port.split(':')
    ip_address = ip_address_list[0]
    print '\'',ip_address,'\''
    if ips_desc.has_key(ip_address):
        count_ip = ips_desc[ip_address]
        count_ip + count_ip +1
        ips_desc[ip_address] +=1
        count_ip =0
    else:
        ips_desc[ip_address] = 1

print ips_desc

myfile = open('blacklist.txt','w')
for ips_items in ips_desc.keys():
myfile.write(ips_items)
```

but last 3 lines dont work any ideas?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Also, it might be Stack Overflow formatting, but that last line should have an indent.

Comment: I assume myfile.write is indented one more, otherwise that would be the problem

Answer (score 2):

Add myfile.close() at the end of your program, or refresh the folder that you are writing to. Because you don't close it, it doesn't always update correctly.
so

```
for line in myfile:
    list_of_line = line.split()
    if 'Failed password for' in line:
        ip_address_port = list_of_line[-4]
        ip_address_list = ip_address_port.split(':')
        ip_address = ip_address_list[0]
        print '\'',ip_address,'\''
    if ips_desc.has_key(ip_address):
        count_ip = ips_desc[ip_address]
        count_ip + count_ip +1
        ips_desc[ip_address] +=1
        count_ip =0
    else:
        ips_desc[ip_address] = 1

print ips_desc

myfile = open('blacklist.txt','w')
for ips_items in ips_desc.keys():
    myfile.write(ips_items)
myfile.close()
```

Comment: that worked how would i say only put ip address init that 13 attempts would it be if ips_item > 13:

Comment: for ips_items in ips_desc.keys(): if ips_items >13: myfile.write(ips_items)

Comment: i got this but it still putting all the ip address in there instead of only one that over 13 attempts. here the code myfile = open('blacklist.txt','w')
for ip in ips_desc.keys():
    if ips_desc > 13:
        myfile.write(ips_items)
myfile.close()

Comment: I think you need if ips_desc[ips_items] > 13: myfile.write(ips_items)

Comment: on myfile.write(ips_items) how would i put new lines so all the ip address are on seprate lines

Comment: myfile.write(str(ipr_items)+'\n')

Answer (score 0):

If you open a file as read only, to write in it (again) you must close it before. So you should do this:

```
myfile.close()
myfile = open('blacklist.txt','w')
for ips_items in ips_desc.keys():
    myfile.write(ips_items)
myfile.close()
```

And maybe it should be:

```
myfile.writelines(ips_items) ?
```

Comment: .write() should work as the keys are ip-adresses(presumably) so it should be only one string

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you didn't close the file.

The previous answer is good but I would suggest that you use the with statement when dealing with files. As so :

```
with open(file, 'w') as myfile:
    myfile.write('something')
```

This way the file is close when you exit the with statement and you'll never have this problem again.